# Count by month with only two date fields - IN and OUT

Tags: mysql, sql

Haven't been able to find an answer to this specific issue.  Need a total count of inventory grouped by month on different products.  Source data has date fields, one for IN and one for OUT.  Total count for a specific month would include an aggregate sum of all rows with an IN date prior to specific month as long as the out date is null or a date after the specific month.

Obviously I can get a count for any given month by writing a query for count(distinct productID) with a WHERE clause stating that the IN Date be before the month I'm interested in (IE September 2012) AND the Out Date is null or after 9/2012:

```
Where ((in_date <= '2012-09-30') AND (out_date >= '2012-09-01' or out_date is null))
```

If the product was even part of inventory for one day in September I want it to count which is why out date above 9/1/12.  Sample data below.  Instead of querying for a specific month, how can I turn this:

Raw Data - Each Row Is Individual Item

```
InDate        OutDate        ProductAttr   ProductID

2008-04-05    NULL           Blue          101
2008-06-04    NULL           Red           125
2008-01-01    2012-06-01     Blue          134
2008-12-10    2012-10-09     Red           129
2009-10-15    2012-11-01     Blue          153
2012-10-01    2013-06-01     Red           149
```

Into this?:

```
Date          ProductAttr    Count
2008-04       Blue           503
2008-04       Red            1002
2008-05       Blue           94
2008-05       Red            3004
2008-06       Blue           2000
2008-06       Red            322
```

Through grouping I can get the raw data into this format grouped by months:

```
InDate       OutDate      Value    Count

2008-05      2012-05      Blue     119
2008-05      2008-06      Red      333
2008-05      2012-10      Blue     4
2008-05      NULL         Red      17488
2008-06      2012-11      Blue     711
2008-06      2013-02      Red      34
```

If you wanted to know how many products were 'IN' as of Oct. 2012- you would sum the counts of all rows except for 2.  Group on Value to keep blue and red separate.  Row 2 is ruled out because OutDate is before Oct. 2012.

Thank in advance.

EDIT:

Gordon Linoff's solution works just like I need it to.  The only issue I am having now is the size and efficiency of the query, because the part I left out above is that the product attribute is actually located in a different table then the IN/OUT dates and I also need to join a third table to limit to a certain type of product (ForSale for example).  I have tried two different approaches and they both work and return the same data, but both take far too long to automate this report:

```
select months.mon, count(distinct d.productID), d.ProductAttr
from (select '2008-10' as mon union all
  select '2008-11' union all
  select '2008-12' union all
  select '2009-01'
 ) months left outer join
 t
 on months.mon >= date_format(t.Indate, '%Y-%m') and 
    (months.mon <= date_format(t.OutDate, '%Y-%m') or t.OutDate is NULL)

join x on x.product_id = t.product_id and x.type = 'ForSale'
join d on d.product_id = x.product_id and d.type = 'Attribute'

group by months.mon, d.ProductAttr;
```

Also tried the above without the last two joins by adding subqueries for the product attribute and where/exclusion - this seems to run about the same or a bit slower:

```
select months.mon, count(distinct t.productID), (select ProductAttr from d where productid = t.productID and type = 'attribute' limit 1)
from (select '2008-10' as mon union all
  select '2008-11' union all
  select '2008-12' union all
  select '2009-01'
 ) months left outer join
 t
 on months.mon >= date_format(t.Indate, '%Y-%m') and 
    (months.mon <= date_format(t.OutDate, '%Y-%m') or t.OutDate is NULL)

WHERE exists (select 1 from x where x.productid = t.productID and x.type = 'ForSale')

group by months.mon, d.ProductAttr;
```

Any ideas to make this more efficient with the additional data that I need to rely on 3 source tables in total (1 just for exclusion).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating a list of the months that you need.  The easiest way is to do this manually in MySQL (although generating the code in Excel can make this easier).

Then use a left join and aggregation to get the information you want:

```
select months.mon, t.ProductAttr, count(distinct t.productID)
from (select '2008-10' as mon union all
      select '2008-11' union all
      select '2008-12' union all
      select '2009-01'
     ) months left outer join
     t
     on months.mon >= date_format(t.Indate, '%Y-%m') and 
        (months.mon <= date_format(t.OutDate, '%Y-%m) or t.OutDate is NULL)
group by t months.mon, t.ProductAttr;
```

This version does all the comparisons as strings.  You are working at the granularity of "month" and the format YYYY-MM does a good job for comparisons.

EDIT:

You do need every month that you want in the output.  If you have products coming in every month, then you could do:

```
select months.mon, t.ProductAttr, count(distinct t.productID)
from (select distinct date_format(t.InDate, '%Y-%m') as mon
      from t
     ) months left outer join
     t
     on months.mon >= date_format(t.InDate, '%Y-%m') and
        (months.mon <= date_format(t.OutDate, '%Y-%m) or t.OutDate is NULL)
group by t months.mon, t.ProductAttr;
```

This pulls the months from the data.

Comment: Do I need to list every month if I want every month from 2008 until now?  I am not sure this handles the issue of (for 2008-10) I would want to sum every row with an in date equal or prior to 10/2008 as long as the out date was after 10/2008 or null.

Comment: @lexthedog . . . Yes, but see the edited version for another possible way to generate the list of months.  Also, I fixed the code to handle `NULL` values for `OutDate`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - added additional information about source tables.  Any ideas for optimizing query?

Comment: sorry should have mentioned username after edits to original question adding info regarding source tables. Any ideas for optimizing query?

Comment: Sorry - was having trouble commenting a replay back using @ because it kept deleting that part when I saved the comment.  Then I realized it does this because I am responding to your answer so it is unnecessary!  Thanks in advance!